# Undefined Method for the type AgentBuilder.Default ByteBuddy

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy

The method rebase(( type) -> {}) is undefined for the type AgentBuilder.Default

```
public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation inst){
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
                    .rebase(type -> type.getSimpleName().equals("Calculator"))
                    .transform((builder, typeDescription) -> builder
                            .method(method -> method.getDeclaredAnnotations()
                            .isAnnotationPresent(Log.class))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogAspect.class)))
                    .installOn(inst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably picked up an outdated API. The step is called type. Your IDE can probably help you here.